# Removing The Nineteenth Byte

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

## Introduction

[The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) is [CGCC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com)'s official chatroom (go check it out!). Its name is a play on [the nineteenth hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteenth_hole), and it also refers to golf, which is appropriate for [CGCC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com)'s chatroom's name. The name is also precisely \$19\$ bytes long, as its name states.

## Challenge

Your task is to write a program that outputs `Stack Exchange Chat - The Nineteenth Byte` exactly. However, if the nineteenth byte and only the nineteenth byte of your source code is removed, it should output only `Stack Exchange Chat`. Because of this, the best score you can get will be \$19\$ bytes. For example, if your code is `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`, then `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` must output `Stack Exchange Chat - The Nineteenth Byte` and `abcdefghijklmnopqrtuvwxyz` must output `Stack Exchange Chat`.

## Rules

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- Trailing whitespace is allowed.
- If possible, please link to an online interpreter (e.g. [TIO](https://tio.run)) to run your program on.
- Please explain your answer. This is not necessary, but it makes it easier for others to understand.
- Languages newer than the question are allowed. This means you could create your own language where it would be trivial to do this, but don't expect any upvotes.
- You are scored by the length of the program that outputs `Stack Exchange Chat - The Nineteenth Byte`.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Brownie points for beating my [40 byte 05AB1E anwer](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOyw02PGmY9ath5aNfRBYfbHrUsUoADw8xHDTOBSg4tf9Qw5XAzmDNPQfdRw9zD@x81rQGiQ0uBmvYfbjncCBQ8tPr/fwA "05AB1E – Try It Online").

Comment: Is this the fastest upvoted challenge in history? 6 upvotes in 17min

Comment: I wish I could learn writing good challenges, for members here

Comment: @ophact Maybe. :P also, got my 05AB1E solution down to [38](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOyw02PGmY9ath5aNfRBYfbHrUsUoADw8xHDTOBSg4tf9Qw5XAzmDNXQfdR0xogOrQUqH7/4ZbDjUDBQ6v//wcA)

Comment: @Wasif hehe i just came up with this idea last night and decided to post it. also i almost have more rep than you :)

Comment: [36 for my solution](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOyw02PGmY9ath5aNfRBYfbHrUsetQwEyh8aPmjhimHm8GcuQq6j5rWANGhpUA1@w@3HG6sqqoCih9arR5@aOGFvcYahxb//w8A "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: [35](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOyw02PGmY9ath5aNfRBYfbHrUsetQwEyh8aPmjhimHm8GcuQq6j5rWANGhpUA1@w@3HG4E8UHa5h5arR5@aOGFvcYahxb//w8A)

Comment: Wow, 32 votes, that's a lotta votes

Comment: @ophact *36 votes

Comment: *38 [filler text]

Comment: I will give a 100 rep bounty to the first person to find a (non-trivial) 19 byte solution in any language.

Comment: Clickbait title. I clicked this thinking it was a meta post about removing the actual chatroom.

Comment: @mbomb007 lmao‎

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
ΣüL½¨ḟKȦΞ×ėCȧt-ξḟ%Nhβ/y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9odXNr///Oo8O8TMK9wqjhuJ9LyKbOnsOXxJdDyKd0Lc6@4bifJU5ozrIvef//)

[Try it online without the 19th byte!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9odXNr///Oo8O8TMK9wqjhuJ9LyKbOnsOXxJdDyKd0Lc6@4bifJWjOsi95//8)

#### Explanation

`¨ḟKȦΞ×ėCȧt-ξḟ%Nhβ/y` is a compressed string, equivalent to `"Stack Exchange Chat - The Nineteenth Byte"`. If we remove `N` (the nineteenth byte of the program) we get `¨ḟKȦΞ×ėCȧt-ξḟ%hβ/y`, which is equivalent to `"Stack Exchange Chat - Thefischer\n Byte"` (`\n` being a newline character).

Now, starting from one of these two strings:

```
  "Stack Exchange Chat - The Nineteenth Byte"    "Stack Exchange Chat - Thefischer\n Byte"

½   Split the string in half
  ["Stack Exchange Chat -",                      ["Stack Exchange Chat",
   " The Nineteenth Byte"]                        " - Thefischer\n Byte"]

üL   nub by length: remove strings with the same length as previous ones
  ["Stack Exchange Chat -",                      ["Stack Exchange Chat"]
   " The Nineteenth Byte"]

Σ   Join the strings together
  "Stack Exchange Chat - The Nineteenth Byte"    "Stack Exchange Chat"
```

Answer (score 24):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 25 bytes

```
“¡TƑ9ı2ṆR“¡⁸¢6ṅȯ*ỵ#K»iƇ”h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDC0OOTbQ8stHo4c62IDD/UeOOQ4vMHu5sPbFe6@Hurcreh3ZnHmt/1DA34/@hRf8B) or [Try it without `#`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDC0OOTbQ8stHo4c62IDD/UeOOQ4vMHu5sPbFe6@Hurd6Hdmcea3/UMDfj/6FF/wE)

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 25 bytes

```
“¡TƑ9ı2ṆR“¡TḟKY=ɱø~»tƑƇ⁶K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDC0OOTbQ8stHo4c62IAj/4Y753pG2Jzce3lF3aHfJsYnH2h81bvP@f2jRfwA) or [Try it without `~`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDC0OOTbQ8stHo4c62IAj/4Y753pG2Jzce3nFod8mxicfaHzVu8/5/aNF/AA)

### How they work

```
“¡TƑ9ı2ṆR“¡⁸¢6ṅȯ*ỵ#K»iƇ”h - Main link. No arguments
“¡TƑ9ı2ṆR“¡⁸¢6ṅȯ*ỵ#K»     - Pair of compressed strings ["Stack Exchange Chat", " - The Nineteenth Byte"]
                      Ƈ   - Keep those for which the following is True:
                     i ”h - They contain "h"; ["Stack Exchange Chat", " - The Nineteenth Byte"]
                            Smash together and output

“¡TƑ9ı2ṆR“¡⁸¢6ṅȯ*ỵK»iƇ”h  - Main link. No arguments
“¡TƑ9ı2ṆR“¡⁸¢6ṅȯ*ỵK»      - Pair of compressed strings ["Stack Exchange Chat", "^Backets reamyappenzell"]
                     Ƈ    - Keep those for which the following is True:
                    i ”h  - They contain "h"; ["Stack Exchange Chat"]
                            Smash together and output
```

And the second one:

```
“¡TƑ9ı2ṆR“¡TḟKY=ɱø~»tƑƇ⁶K - Main link. No arguments
“¡TƑ9ı2ṆR“¡TḟKY=ɱø~»      - Pair of compressed strings ["Stack Exchange Chat", "- The Nineteenth Byte"]
                     ƑƇ   - Keep those where the following has no effect:
                    t  ⁶  -   Removing spaces from the front and end; ["Stack Exchange Chat", "- The Nineteenth Byte"]
                        K - Join with spaces; "Stack Exchange Chat - The Nineteenth Byte"

“¡TƑ9ı2ṆR“¡TḟKY=ɱø»tƑƇ⁶K  - Main link. No arguments
“¡TƑ9ı2ṆR“¡TḟKY=ɱø»       - Pair of compressed strings ["Stack Exchange Chat", " Backets reamyappenzell"]
                    ƑƇ    - Keep those where the following has no effect:
                   t  ⁶   -   Removing spaces from the front and end; ["Stack Exchange Chat"]
                       K  - Join with spaces; "Stack Exchange Chat"
```

Comment: Welp, time to go change my name to `Backets reamyappenzell`

Comment: @pxeger *inspired by his "many users of ppcg* answer

Comment: How does `#` turn `^Backets reamyappenzell` into ` - The Nineteenth Byte`?

Comment: @Jonah The `#` is part of a compressed string (delimited with `“...»`. Compressed strings work by treating their contents as a base-250 number, with each digit being a character in Jelly's code page, then repeatedly breaking up that number to generating words and characters. Adding or removing the `#` changes this base-250 number (same way that `12345` and `1245` are different numbers in base 10), and so would decompress to a different string

Comment: @pxeger Careful, I learnt the hard way that name changes stick with you for far longer than you thought...

Answer (score 15):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
“ÆçƲBnƥẈṛⱮ_ỴȷOṘỵḊĊ»»ḣ19$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATsAxP9qZWxsef//4oCcw4bDp8ayQm7GpeG6iOG5m@Kxrl/hu7TIt0/huZjhu7XhuIrEisK7wrvhuKMxOST//w)

### Without the nineteenth byte

```
“ÆçƲBnƥẈṛⱮ_ỴȷOṘỵḊĊ»ḣ19$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9qZWxsef//4oCcw4bDp8ayQm7GpeG6iOG5m@Kxrl/hu7TIt0/huZjhu7XhuIrEisK74bijMTkk//8)

It works no matter if you index from 0 or 1!

### Explanation

```
“ÆçƲBnƥẈṛⱮ_ỴȷOṘỵḊĊ»»ḣ19$   Main niladic link
“ÆçƲBnƥẈṛⱮ_ỴȷOṘỵḊĊ»        "Stack Exchange Chat - The Nineteenth Byte"
                   »       [Calculate the byte-wise maximum with]*
                       $   (
                    ḣ19      Get the first 19 characters
                       $   )
```

*When indexing from 1, it's actually the first `»` that is removed, but the result is the same.

Comment: explanation please?

Comment: @Makonede Added

Answer (score 14):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 66 bytes

The nineteenth byte is the `X`.

```javascript
print("Stack",(s="X"&&" - The Nineteenth Byte","Exchange Chat"+s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxCoAgEADQXzluECXdW1qK1pYaWg850gIRPaS@3t67qVH1JWZxbew9l5hE4y7kH7S6TniiUggOjsCwxcTCnCTA/AmjxfX1gdLFsAQSHKoxvf8)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBCoAgDADQXxk7hJLeu3QpunapHxgy0gIRHVJfv967qVMLNRXxfVItNWUxeAiFB51pM@IwIHg4I8OeMgtzlgjLJ4wOtzdEyhfDGklwbNaq/g) (nineteenth byte removed)

#### Commented

```javascript
print(                            // print:
  "Stack",                        //   the first word followed by an implicit space
  (                               //
    s = "X" &&                    //   define s as either " - The Nineteenth Byte"
        " - The Nineteenth Byte", //   or an empty string if the 'X' is removed
    "Exchange Chat" + s           //   append "Exchange Chat" followed by s
  )                               //
)                                 // end
```

Comment: this was my original strategy (no mistakes) but then I decided to golf it more (failed) +1

Comment: @Wasif apparent error that went unnoticed when I was creating my solution

Comment: @ophact Oh, I see. Variables that are defined only on some code paths are sometimes misleading. :-/

Comment: yeah, got +3 votes for some reason. At least I got the Disciplined badge...

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 66 bytes

```python
s,y='Stack Exch',01
print s+'ange Chat'+' - The Nineteenth Byte'*y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v1in0lY9uCQxOVvBtSI5Q13HwJCroCgzr0ShWFs9MS89VcE5I7FEXVtdQVchJCNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEPBqbIkVV2r8v9/AA)

Not really a smart answer. :p

The nineteenth byte here is the `1`.

y is `0` or `1` depending on if the nineteenth byte is removed.

*thanks to pxeger for -2 bytes*

Comment: 66 (idea stolen from @ophact's JS answer): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v1in0lY9uCQxOVvBtSI5Q13HwJCroCgzr0ShWFs9MS89VcE5I7FEXVtdQVchJCNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEPBqbIkVV2r8v9/AA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @pxeger good catch but sadly Neil pointed out a mistake in my answer which forced me to delete it. The octal number was probably the only takeaway from the answer

Comment: @pxeger cool. Actually I had tried the same trick in Python 3, but `y=01` gives syntax error there. Not sure why the behaviour is like that.

Comment: @ManishKundu `01` is octal, but that's not obvious to look at unless you're familiar with C already, so it was removed in favour of an `0o` prefix in Python 3

Answer (score 12):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 54 bytes

```sh
set Exchange Chat \
- The Nineteenth Byte
<<<Stack\ $@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/OLVEwbUiOSMxLz1VwTkjsUQhhktXISQjVcEvMy@1JDU1ryRDwamyJJXLxsYmuCQxOTtGQcXh/38A)

`set` assigns the given words to the default variable `$@`. As with the previous one, `\` joins the two lines into one call to set, instead of treating `- The Nineteenth Byte` as a command (which does nothing).

---

### [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 55 bytes

```sh
1=" Exchange Chat"\
" - The Nineteenth Byte"
<<<Stack$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/f0FZJwbUiOSMxLz1VwTkjsUQphktJQVchJCNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEPBqbIkVYnLxsYmuCQxOVvF8P9/AA)

Idea boringly copied from [@xnor's genius answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221334). The `\` escapes the newline, which concatenates the two strings; without it, the second line is ignored as an undefined command.

---

### [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 58 bytes

```sh
1=Stack\ Exchang
2=" - The Nineteenth Byte"
<<<$1e\ Chat$2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/f0Da4JDE5O0bBtSI5IzEvncvIVklBVyEkI1XBLzMvtSQ1Na8kQ8GpsiRVicvGxkbFMDVGwTkjsUTF6P9/AA)

The 19th byte is the second `=`, which changes that line from a variable assignment to an undefined command which does nothing. Then, when printing, `$2` defaults to empty.

Answer (score 11):

## [Emotion](https://github.com/Quantum64/Emotion), 34 [bytes](https://quantum64.github.io/EmotionBuilds/1.1.0///?state=JTdCJTIybW9kZSUyMiUzQSUyMmNvZGVwYWdlJTIyJTdE)

```
☝
```

The nineteenth byte is .

[Try it online!](https://quantum64.github.io/EmotionBuilds/1.1.0///?state=JTdCJTIyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJDb2RlJTIyJTNBJTIyJUYwJTlGJTk4JTg3JUYwJTlGJTk4JTk4JUYwJTlGJUE3JTk2JUYwJTlGJTlBJUI1JUYwJTlGJUE3JTk2JUYwJTlGJTkyJUFCJUYwJTlGJTk4JThCJUYwJTlGJUE3JTk2JUYwJTlGJTkyJTk5JUYwJTlGJUE0JTk5JUYwJTlGJTkyJTgxJUYwJTlGJUE0JUI5JUUyJTk4JTlEJUYwJTlGJThEJTkzJUYwJTlGJUE3JTk2JUYwJTlGJTkyJTk2JUYwJTlGJThEJUI4JUYwJTlGJTk4JTlBJUYwJTlGJUE0JTk1JUYwJTlGJTk4JTk0JUYwJTlGJTk4JTk4JUYwJTlGJTk4JTg5JUYwJTlGJTkyJTlBJUYwJTlGJTk5JThDJUYwJTlGJTk5JThFJUYwJTlGJUE1JUE1JUYwJTlGJUE0JUE0JUYwJTlGJTkxJUE4JUYwJTlGJUE0JTkxJUYwJTlGJTkyJTg3JUYwJTlGJTkxJUIxJUYwJTlGJTkyJTk0JUYwJTlGJTk4JUFGJUYwJTlGJTk4JUE4JTIyJTJDJTIyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJBcmd1bWVudHMlMjIlM0ElMjIlMjIlMkMlMjJtb2RlJTIyJTNBJTIyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXIlMjIlN0Q=)

Comment: Is this language made for golfing? Also, is there a tutorial I can learn from?

Comment: @Razetime It's a language I made for golfing a couple of years ago, except it's not very efficient. Currently, I am rewriting the entire language with a different type system and may make a tutorial on the new version.

Answer (score 11):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 69 bytes

Without the removal of the 19th byte, the full string (which is much less than 119 characters) is printed; if the 19th byte is removed, only 19 characters are printed instead.

```c
main(){printf("%.119s","Stack Exchange Chat - The Nineteenth Byte");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQ0lVz9DQslhJRym4JDE5W8G1IjkjMS89VcE5I7FEQVchJCNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEPBqbIkVUnTuvb/fwA)

With the 19th byte removed: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQ0lVz9CyWElHKbgkMTlbwbUiOSMxLz1VwTkjsURBVyEkI1XBLzMvtSQ1Na8kQ8GpsiRVSdO69v9/AA)

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 58 bytes

```python
s="Exchange Chat "\
"- The Nineteenth Byte"
print"Stack",s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9hWybUiOSMxLz1VwTkjsURBKYZLSVchJCNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEPBqbIkVYmroCgzr0QpuCQxOVtJp/j/fwA) ([no 19th byte](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9hWybUiOSMxLz1VwTkjsURBiUtJVyEkI1XBLzMvtSQ1Na8kQ8GpsiRViaugKDOvRCm4JDE5W0mn@P9/AA))

The 19th byte is the `\` at the end of the first line. It acts as a line continuation character to make the full line be `"Exchange Chat ""- The Nineteenth Byte"` using Python's automatic concatenation of adjacent string literals.

Without the `\`, the line ends there, and the second line is lonely string value that doesn't do anything. The truncated string ends in a space, which is fine because the challenge allows for trailing whitespace.

---

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 61 bytes**

```python
s="Exchange Chat"+--1*" - The Nineteenth Byte"
print"Stack",s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9hWybUiOSMxLz1VwTkjsURJW1fXUEtJQVchJCNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEPBqbIkVYmroCgzr0QpuCQxOVtJp/j/fwA) ([no 19th byte](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9hWybUiOSMxLz1VwTkjsURJW9dQS0lBVyEkI1XBLzMvtSQ1Na8kQ8GpsiRViaugKDOvRCm4JDE5W0mn@P9/AA))

The 19th byte is a `-`. Originally we append `--1` (so, `1`) copies of the string `" - The Nineteenth Byte"`, with the  19th byte is removed, this is `-1` copies which is nothing.

Answer (score 8):

## Scala 3, 90 bytes

```scala
val x="Stack Ex"+a/*/ */+" - The Nineteenth Byte"
def a="change Chat"
@main def m=print(x)
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/RIMt9dBVSaGLXFopkJpO3Q)

With the nineteenth byte removed:

```scala
val x="Stack Ex"+a// */+" - The Nineteenth Byte"
def a="change Chat"
@main def m=print(x)
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/dlYCNGoWRmCBsKFUxvUclw)

The syntax highlighting should show what happens. This would be a byte shorter in a language without nested comments, since the space in `/*/ */` wouldn't be needed, but I just like Scala :P

A possible solution with a newline that doesn't work because of parsing rules:

```scala
val x="Stack E"+a//
+" - The Nineteenth Byte"
def a="xchange Chat"
@main def m=print(x)
```

Comment: first answer to make use of comments, +1

Comment: Hi, until what reputation you'll award the bounties on good old question answers?

Comment: @Wasif I'll award them as long as I don't go below 5000 when I award one, so feel free to answer some old questions! (btw if you have any more questions, could you please ask in chat or on comments to the actual post?)

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 72 bytes

```python
print('Stack Exch{1}'.format(x:='ange Chat',x+' - The Nineteenth Byte'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EQz24JDE5W8G1Ijmj2rBWXS8tvyg3sUSjwspWPTEvPVXBOSOxRF2nQltdQVchJCNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEPBqbIkVV1T8/9/AA)

Different approach than @ManishKundu solution

Nineteenth byte is `1` removing it will result `0` to only suffix `hange Chat`

Thanks to @ZaelinGoodman for insight

-6 bytes to @Makonede

Comment: [-5](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EQym4JDE5W8G1IrnawLBWSS8tvyg3sUSjwspWPSMxLz1VwTkjsURdp0JbXUFXISQjVcEvMy@1JDU1ryRDIamyJFVdU/P/fwA) with the [walrus operator `:=`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572).

Comment: [-1 more](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EQym4JDE5W8G1Ijmj2rBWSS8tvyg3sUSjwspWPTEvPVXBOSOxRF2nQltdQVchJCNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEMhqbIkVV1T8/9/AA) (for a total of -6) making use of implicit `str.format` arguments: `'a{}b{}c'.format('1','2') -> 'a1b2c'`

Comment: Also, it's better to [be consistent with quotes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EQz24JDE5W8G1Ijmj2rBWXS8tvyg3sUSjwspWPTEvPVXBOSOxRF2nQltdQVchJCNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEMhqbIkVV1T8/9/AA). EDIT: [corrected a capitalization error in your code](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EQz24JDE5W8G1Ijmj2rBWXS8tvyg3sUSjwspWPTEvPVXBOSOxRF2nQltdQVchJCNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEPBqbIkVV1T8/9/AA).

Comment: Please fix the capitalization error in your code as well. And it's recommended (but not necessary) to stick to a single type of quotation marks the whole program.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 65 bytes

```python
b='Stack Excha'
n=88
print b+'nge Chat - The Nineteenth Byte'[:n]
```

**[Try all of it](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8lWPbgkMTlbwbUiOSNRnSvP1sKCq6AoM69EIUlbPS89VcE5I7FEQVchJCNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEPBqbIkVT3aKi/2/38A)**
**[Try it without the 19th byte](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8lWPbgkMTlbwbUiOSNRnSvP1oKroCgzr0QhSVs9Lz1VwTkjsURBVyEkI1XBLzMvtSQ1Na8kQ8GpsiRVPdoqL/b/fwA)**

Works in Python 3 trivially for [66 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P8lWPbgkMTlbwbUiOSNRnSvP1sKCq6AoM69EI0lbPS89VcE5I7FEQVchJCNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEPBqbIkVT3aKi9W8/9/AA)

Answer (score 8):

## Scratch 3.0, 10 blocks/160 bytes

```
define
set[outpuuut v]to[Stack Exchange Chat - The Nineteenth Byte
set[outpuuu v]to[Stack Exchange Chat
if<(outpuuut)>(0)>then
say(outpuuut
else
say(outpuuu
end
```

This outputs `Stack Exchange Chat - The Nineteenth Byte`

Because Scratch is a block-based language, it may not seem obvious on how to remove a byte at first. But thankfully, there exists a text format called ScratchBlocks which [we seem to allow for scoring](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5013/78850). The above ScratchBlocks corresponds to the following real blocks:

[image: This actually wasn't as painful as I thought it'd be]

[Try it on Scratch!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/506212911/)

Removing the 19th byte of this program gives

```
define
set[outpuuu v]to[Stack Exchange Chat - The Nineteenth Byte
set[outpuuu v]to[Stack Exchange Chat
if<(outpuuut)>(0)>then
say(outpuuut
else
say(outpuuu
end
```

This outputs `Stack Exchange Chat`

[image]

[Try it on Scratch!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/506216881/)

Explanation coming soon

Comment: Could the variable names be shortened by lengthening the function name?

Comment: @ophact They can actually! This saves 23 bytes.

Answer (score 7):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <del>95 94</del> 87 bytes

Saved 1 precious byte thanks to @OriginalOriginalOriginalVI!
Saved 7 more bytes thanks to @Bubbler!

```factor
"Stack Exchange C"f " - The Nineteenth Byte""hat"rot [ prepend nip ] [ glue ] if* print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY0xDsIwEAS/sroSiQ9AB0KIJk2giigss46tRBfjXCTyehPoZpqZ4LxNpT7aW3M9YGBRjsiFZmsuSQ0z3wvVc0aacKzSmvMDLh8fnfbEWQIEe9wj0SSlkWoRp9UoEp1JmQzdr5ipL2jKeG7ejws3SGGH/6bWLw)

Explained:

```factor
"Stack Exchange C"f " - The Nineteenth Byte""hat"  ! push items on the stack,
                                                   ! f (false) value is 19th char
rot                                                ! rotate, f now at top of stack
                                                   ! if f is missing, "Stack Exchange C"
                                                   ! is at the top
[ prepend nip ] [ glue] if* print                  ! if* f is found, glue the strings and print.
                                                   ! if* a string is found, it is considered to
                                                   ! be true, retain it on the stack, swap & glue
                                                   ! the top strings, drop the "19th Byte" string,
                                                   ! append and print.
```

Old version:

```factor
"Stack Exchange C"f "hat"" - The Nineteenth Byte"rot [ nip swap append ] [ 3append ] if* print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc2xCgIxEEXRX3mkFKzstFNEbLZZrcRiiC8mrMxmkxHdr49iYXc5zQ3ibSzt3B@7wxoDi/KBXGg255LUUDk9qZ4VacSmud7ED9i/fRS9EzsX4KKYc1jiFIkuKY1Ui9jORldGwwWaMupLMiRn6g3Xr63@ncICv1trHw)

Explained:

```factor
"Stack Exchange C"f "hat"" - The Nineteenth Byte"  ! push items on the stack,
                                                   ! f (false) value is 19th char
rot                                                ! rotate, f now at top of stack
                                                   ! if f is missing, "Stack Exchange C"
                                                   ! is at the top
[ nip swap append ] [ 3append ] if* print          ! if* f is found, append the strings and print.
                                                   ! if* a string is found, it is considered to
                                                   ! be true, retain it on the stack, drop the
                                                   ! "19th Byte" string, swap stack strings,
                                                   ! append and print.
```

Comment: Doesn't the `USING` statement count as part of the code?

Comment: @Makonede No, it doesn't. Looks like those are all standard.

Comment: By the way, you can remove the space before `rot`.

Comment: @OriginalOriginalOriginalVI oops I missed it! thanks!

Comment: `glue` is a shorter word to join three strings. Though it has different argument order, it doesn't matter much here. Also, `prepend` is shorter than `swap append`. [87 bytes.](https://tio.run/##HY0xDsIwEAS/sroSiQ9AB0KIJk2giigss46tRBfjXCTyehPoZpqZ4LxNpT7aW3M9YGBRjsiFZmsuSQ0z3wvVc0aacKzSmvMDLh8fnfbEWQIEe9wj0SSlkWoRp9UoEp1JmQzdr5ipL2jKeG7ejws3SGGH/6bWLw)

Comment: @Bubbler I missed those two words in the manual somehow.. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 7):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 62 bytes

```
"Stack Exch"\" - "<
" tahC egna"/r>o<r/
eeteniN ehT"\"etyB htn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/Xym4JDE5W8G1IjlDKUZJQVdByYZLSaEkMcNZITU9L1FJv8gu36ZInys1tSQ1L9NPITUjBKgutaTSSSGjJO//fwA)

[Try it without the Nineteenth byte](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/Xym4JDE5W8G1IjlDKUZJQVdBiUtJoSQxw1khNT0vUUm/yC7fpkifKzW1JDUv008hNSMEqCy1pNJJIaMk7/9/AA)

I've been playing around with ><> this week and this one was kind of a freebie, although it still turned out to be an interesting packing problem that ended up getting quite lucky at the end.

The Nineteenth byte is unsurprisingly the `<` at the end of the first row. With or without it, we'll execute `"Stack Exchange Chat "`, pushing that string onto the stack (in reverse order; usually we want to push strings backwards but here it's convenient to start with the prefix so we'll just reverse the stack later instead).

At this point, the program encounters the `/` at the end of the second row, hitting it from the right and heading down, *conveniently going through the space between "Nineteenth" and "Byte"*, then wrapping around vertically and either heading leftwards on the first or second row. With the `<`, we execute `"The Nineteenth Byte"`, pushing that string on the stack and then head to the output gadget, and without it we head directly to the output.

The output is done by first reversing the stack with `r`, and then heading into the bottomless pit of `>o<` which executes the output instruction `o` endlessly until the stack is emptied and the program exits via error.

Answer (score 6):

## PowerShell 7, 60 bytes

```powershell
'Stack Exchange'+(!0 ?' Chat - The Nineteenth Byte':' Chat')
#                 ^
#                 19th byte
```

No TIO because the ternary operator is not supported in powershell 6 and below

### Alternate Solutions

#### PowerShell 7, 60 bytes

```powershell
"Stack Exchan$($x=!0 ?' - The Nineteenth Byte':'')ge Chat$x"
#                 ^
#                 19th byte
```

#### PowerShell, <sup><strike>61</strike></sup> 58 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to @mazzy!!

```powershell
"Stack Exchange {01}"-f'Chat','Chat - The Nineteenth Byte'
#                 ^
#                 19th byte
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f9fKbgkMTlbwbUiOSMxLz1VodrAsFZJN03dOSOxRF0HTCnoKoRkpCr4ZeallqSm5pVkKDhVlqSqc2FqJVLn//8A)

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f9fKbgkMTlbwbUiOSMxLz1VodrAsFZJN03dOSOxRF0HTCnoKoRkpCr4ZeallqSm5pVkKDhVlqSqc2FqJVLn//8A "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")?

Comment: @mazzy I had a feeling you'd come along and find a smarter way to do one of my secondary solutions lol. Thanks!

Comment: fair competition of alternatives :)

Answer (score 5):

## Java, <s>104</s> <s>83</s> 72 bytes

```
$->"Stack ExchangeA Chat".replaceAll("A(.*)","$1 - The Nineteenth Byte")
```

The nineteenth byte is `A`.

*Saved 21 bytes thanks to [79037662](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/89930).*

*Saved 11 bytes thanks to [Olivier Grégoire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16236).*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU09a8MwEN3zKw6RQSqxoHPagBOSLV1cuoQOV0W25VxkYZ1CTclvd1Vi@pb3uHsfHd6w6M6XKaQvcgYMYYxwROfhZwEZ8z0ycqZb785wzV9Z8eB8c/oEHJqoZvMfutyoEzvSdfKGXe/1YRYvHzm@eiQ3UL9Oy2IjKkZzgf23adE3toRdiyz0YAOhsSWRFKXUT0qsxPIZCnhvLbw5b9lazy1sR7ZCTev/@WqMbK@6T6xD3mHystYYAo3SJyKlHtb74j79Ag)

[Try it online (without the nineteenth byte)!](https://tio.run/##PU09T8MwEN37K05WBxs1lpiBSi2CDZYgFsRwuJfE6dWx4nNFhPrbg1Ej3vKe7t5Hj2es@sNxjvmLvQPHmBK8oA/ws4KC5Z4EpdB58Ac4la@uZfSh/fgEHNtkFvMf@tJos3i2TQ5O/BDs8yLu30t8c01uoXmY19VW1YLuCE/frsPQEjx2KMqOFBkd7Zi12ml7Y9RGrW@hgreO4NUHEqIgHewnIWXmu//1ekpCJztksbHMCAfdWIyRJx0yszFX62V1mX8B)

Comment: Replace `==18` with `<19`, and `("Ec","Exc")` with `("E","Ex")` to easily save a few bytes.

Comment: Save some bytes by not using `length` and `replace`, which are long function names. Here the first `1` is the 19th byte: https://tio.run/##PY5Pa8MwDMXv/RTC9JCwxqzXpX@gZbutl4xdxg6a6yROXSXYcmgo@eyZR8N@FwnpvSc12GPWnC9TF36sUaAseg/vaAjuC4jMc8/IsfStOcM1bpOCnaHq6xvQVT6dxX80MVEGNlaWgRSbluTb3Gw@o331cO6g3E7LbHfv0YHfPs@sc6c5OBIFo7rA603VSJWGY40snhK/We@FeBGQwUet4WRIs9bENRwG1iLNxyn//6QYPOurbAPLLp5kS0kpsevskFCwNk0f0nExTr8

Comment: @79037662 Great idea! Thanks.

Comment: [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##PU09a8MwEN3zKw6RQSqxoHPagBOSLV1cuoQOV0W25VxkYZ1CTclvd1Vi@pb3uHsfHd6w6M6XKaQvcgYMYYxwROfhZwEZ8z0ycqZb785wzV9Z8eB8c/oEHJqoZvMfutyoEzvSdfKGXe/1YRYvHzm@eiQ3UL9Oy2IjKkZzgf23adE3toRdiyz0YAOhsSWRFKXUT0qsxPIZCnhvLbw5b9lazy1sR7ZCTev/@WqMbK@6T6xD3mHystYYAo3SJyKlHtb74j79Ag)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Good one.

Answer (score 5):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 90 bytes

```
              Y =1
	X =GT(Y) ' - The Nineteenth Byte'
	OUTPUT ='Stack Exchange Chat' X
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcGxDkAwFAXQuf2Ku5XBILF2QWNDohLGkhcVUoM38PU1O@cO13KdRYz4maFzKSboxiZzCoUM1hPaPRATBfYoXyYlRTfafrTQamC3HjDP6l3YCJV3rDBJ09Yxfg)

The nineteenth byte here is the `1`. SNOBOL treats an empty string as `0`, and an empty right-hand assignment as an empty string. So when the byte is removed, the program assigns a value of `0` to `Y`, and the comparison `Y GT` (implicit 0) fails, hence `X` is assigned an empty value as well.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 27 bytes

```
” -€€¥ŠteenthÄÁ” õs”Â‚‹ºŠÆÿ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcNcBd1HTWuA6NDSowtKUlPzSjIOtxxuBEkc3loMpA43PWqY9ahh56FdRxccbju8//9/AA) and [Try it without `s`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcNcBd1HTWuA6NDSowtKUlPzSjIOtxxuBEkc3gokDzc9apj1qGHnoV1HFxxuO7z//38A)

```python
” -€€¥ŠteenthÄÁ” # Compressed string " - The Nineteenth Byte"
 õ               # push the empty string
 (s)             # (swap back to the other string)
   ”Â‚‹ºŠÆÿ      # push compressed string "Stack Exchange Chatÿ"
                 # where ÿ is replaced by the string on the top of the stack
```

Comment: `s` can also be `‎\‎` or `Š`.

Answer (score 4):

## Excel, <s>73</s> 70 bytes

*Updated thanks to @EngineeringToast*

```
=LET(a,"Stack ",b,1,a&"Exchange Chat"&IF(b," - The Nineteenth Byte",))
```

*Original*

```
=LET(s,"Sta",n,30--11,LEFT(s&"ck Exchange Chat - The Nineteenth Byte",n))
```

Shows all characters as is; the left 19 characters if the 19th byte (-) is deleted.

Comment: 71 bytes: `=LET(a,"Stack ",b,10,a&"Exchange Chat"&IF(b," - The Nineteenth Byte",))` where the 19th bytes is the `1` inside `b,10`.

Comment: Thanks @EngineerToast.  We can get it down to 70 eliminating the 0.

Answer (score 4):

## [shortC](https://github.com/aaronryank/shortC), 54 bytes

```
Ds"Exchange Chat\x20- The Nineteenth Byte"
AJ"Stack "s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87ILypJ/v/fpVjJtSI5IzEvPVXBOSOxJKbCyEBXISQjVcEvMy@1JDU1ryRDwamyJFWJy9FLKbgkMTlbQan4/39DAA)

#### Without the Nineteenth byte

```
Ds"Exchange Chat\x0- The Nineteenth Byte"
AJ"Stack "s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87ILypJ/v/fpVjJtSI5IzEvPVXBOSOxJKbCQFchJCNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEPBqbIkVYnL0UspuCQxOVtBqfj/f0MA)

`\x20` denotes a space character, removing the `2` we get `\x0` (null character) which in C is the string terminator.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>72</s> <s>68</s> 63 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to Dominic van Essen.

```r
cat(scan(,"",3+0004))
Stack Exchange Chat - The Nineteenth Byte
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKM4OTFPQ0dJScdY28DAwERTkyu4JDE5W8G1IjkjMS89VcE5I7FEQVchJCNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEPBqbIk9f9/AA)

The 19th byte is the `4`. In the unaltered version, `scan` will read 7 words from the next line, and then print them. If you remove the `4`, `scan` will read only 3 words and then print them.

Comment: [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8JWybUiOSMxLz1VybrSNjNNw9BAU0lXISQjVcEvMy@1JDU1ryRDwamyBCifnFiioRRckpicraRToaPknJFYoqRTqfn/PwA)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Nice, thanks! I had tried `if(10)y=...` but that led to an error when `y` is not defined; setting to `NULL` with your solution is elegant.

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##DcFBCoBACADAr4gnhYL6QtG1S31AxHIJ9rBI1OutmZapEtTsJqVyEPyGkbGH3Q3WUi3MajhMbxh2uIXoBcujLvU0mF0CmTnzAw) is also 68 bytes, and seems really wasteful with all the whitespace, but I don't know if it can be golfed any more...

Answer (score 4):

## [Foo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo), 46 bytes

```
"Stack Exchange Ch"at"at - The Nineteenth Byte
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vP//9fKbgkMTlbwbUiOSMxLz1VwTlDKbEEiBR0FUIyUhX8MvNSS1JT80oyFJwqS1L//wcA)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vP//9fKbgkMTlbwbUiOSMxLz1VwTkjsUQpsURBVyEkI1XBLzMvtSQ1Na8kQ8GpsiT1/38A)

Output the quoted strings, which don't have to be closed. Other commands don't matter.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 63 bytes

```hs
main=putStr$take 119"Stack Exchange Chat - The Nineteenth Byte"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcY7CoAwDADQq4TiWrD@HVwUVxe9QCjBlGoRjaCnr4tveoyXp22LWudFWdVNm5rsX9zRhe64ZZYzEfQExrRqFrQexscyhpVgYBTQsDDB5AIJURCG/hVSMX4)

The 19th byte is the center `1` in `119`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 60 bytes

```
"Stack Exc"~Print~##&["hange Chat"," - The Nineteenth Byte"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYyxCsIwEEB3vyJcxakOjg6CqB1cREi30OEIlyZILyE9oSL216Po5PLgweMNKJ4GlGCxuN1S2xySnDndRUsO3Jfrh2Jct2hjM6VM4xgi792//tpTjsm4@rnZvrpSQAvam2omC/N3MlfVyoBH7kkdPQrUoNaq9aQugUmIWLw6PISgewM)

The 19th byte is one of the `#`s. `##` represents a sequence of all arguments, but `#` represents only the first argument.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 61 bytes

```apl
¯12⌽∊('ge Chat'{⍺ ⍵}' - The Nineteenth Byte'),'Stack Exchan'
```

```apl
¯12⌽∊  ⍝ Rotate right 12
{⍺ ⍵}  ⍝ Concatenate
,      ⍝ Concatenate
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v//0HpDo0c9ex91dGmop6cqOGcklqhXP@rdpfCod2utuoKuQkhGqoJfZl5qSWpqXkmGglNlSaq6po56cElicraCa0VyRmKeOhe1zMFpCvFGAAA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I think you left a newline at the end, but you can also do [this](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v9fQz05W8G1IjkjMS89VcE5I7FEXedR12J1BV2FkIxUBb/MvNSS1NS8kgwFp8qSVHVNnUe9K9SDSxLVKdDKhUUnURoB) for 53 bytes.

Comment: @Original Actually, he has posted here before.

Comment: @Makonede Right, but I thought it would be appropriate to welcome them to CGCC, since they're a new contributor.

Comment: @OriginalOriginalOriginalVI Dang it, I knew there should be a way to use left tack. The selfie seems so obvious now, good call.

Comment: @OriginalOriginalOriginalVI I am new, but I've answered one other :) https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220985/92642

Comment: @OriginalOriginalOriginalVI Sorry, I don't see what you mean about the newline.

Comment: There's a newline after the last quote, but it appears to not be part of the code. (btw your first answer is pretty cool too :) )

Comment: @OriginalOriginalOriginalVI Thanks! I'm glad I discovered code golf, it makes learning a new language less tedious :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 51 bytes

```
Stack Exchange Chat - The Nineteenth Byte
ht.*
hat
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fK7gkMTlbwbUiOSMxLz1VwTkjsURBVyEkI1XBLzMvtSQ1Na8kQ8GpsiSVK6NET4sLKP3/PwA) Explanation: Tries to insert the whole string, but if the 19th byte (the `a`) is deleted, then replaces everything after the `C` with `hat`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), filename: 2 bytes + content: 64 bytes = 66 bytes.

Thank you for commenting me that I need to use content of the file.

### Filename

```
.e
```

### Content

```
Stack Exchange Cha.p.c.c.zt - The Nineteenth Byte.p.d.a.v.st.v.p
```

### How it works

- Every command substring consists of a dot and a char.
- Every non-command substring is considered to be a command to push each of the string from backwards.

  - I.e. literals.
- Filename is main routine; content is subroutine.
- `.e` calls subroutine.
- 19th byte on content is `.` of `.p` --- a command to pop each to putchar().

  - Then the stack would be empty.
- `.c` is dup() iff not empty; nop() otherwise.
- `.z ... .a` is `while size<2 || pop!=pop; do ... ;done`.
- `.d` is exit() on filename; `return` on content.
- `.v` reverses entire stack.

### Links to TIO

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nRhrV@JG9Ht/xTAFMgOEAOKuyzhaRXdLq6xVu90VqCdCkGhIAgkKAvvXt/dOEgTXnj6Ox2Ry5859v4aeGQy@/UgGYegHNcO4tcPB5KbY9YbGh5/1S9@03puPT5Zr@FNrWPS9wJ7awdC4cbwbY2jaEdwuVopD211t/xBYIdGtiZgMzeCelEqVirCmvjcOyUn9@uDkRNYFC2e@RW6tsOu5/WxWfQHXoen2@J7Rsx4Md@I4pLKXLWez8eGzg8ufJU2zGI/ofkJAbfH0HF/52jJa6EuasP292fh8fXF5JCul0lYCPPt40fh88uW6/vH8/Lh@KcuiRXSX0PT88ODi5@tPx@cXjY/NGpAhnWx2TpRWHlFaCvzIH4rl6szVa0es4cQxQ4sEAzzg@SGsHr1xL/AdOxSmY5sB0W@Jlp6X8zT9E11qUsO3Jpq/n5zUT49kTbEApZFhTwQDux8q5j2CiDHA6g48kv6RUyJJGVkzBQkGFtgw9DziOb29LHrBDkmZC@vBdAhNkb7pBBZdLF5BJ@v4SgKFM10EVo9ogTE1ZoYI4PFkaIrvE@ksFqCyogQ437EFTcACzoN8906AC33bsRhnfVkSXTOwgEOZEtslrJ/jpA/eEFZgdoUZBNbwxpmh4z3w@YFL9IdwUl6EY6LXA1IqV7aq22/e7rwjWqvt5jra4nZs@aS4MB/viXZ4/KHRnDvApCerbwRYl/lj2w37RPPPvI9u025cd@vBxcOn/nvreHz@@Mf08@zL05V5EF4OT3tHeT2VzmS0xf9gnS5JWm9Rki4R2pFtSsEkjvdojVkQicBopksL6RLnhLapoAIMqanQYJQWLgq0RrlA0fsykJSKvjdmAiLesV2L9PdKgs/tPksAwa4scYUHwAAtWc9m@1L2@PyYcaFYknor6IilBV4niKV2HwfoiWh9wvoc2YmXhKMdJKScWRLL5YrN9wwUh@jICQs4ABBj2Z@43dD2XHLCukr2bgrk5UFodu9bTj7fkd01JDiCOA6fxx6jTmwDB3R3dJ0ncPiLaejlTiwI2GG51JQn9AfiQfio4KNJSERaxzrugYJuXhqtx@nsqWPohmmgBdzdUsycFk1yWCXFCIEuaNeEiIbYpqvgVnjgaxZRMTvGPiU/gWhuHsjVQE8k6SmdjJ6RzaZcHtsygvD5RLp6WUSSuXuTdfcqH8SiREKQR8MjRfNVWV7qEglHzVgewFDuc/8DycTtEKMitnsmaLex9iUpShesRSIzE90JSQUrEVBaJF4wZQlfEKTpPsXVAABakAOT@Z7bDR7GYcfIMXO3zPNGKw@Zp0ffFQ7@saahWBq@MQcyIoACsQx2ywL@460BrAageGjkUilTLOeBTBmtvhV7Q5hoFPu6Y@QNB6g23@vAhpngexCgC4ZqeW4AAgBwgEBjaOiwXYZVIotYliFJX6i5taGmNj9r2flSR6bBr/m88CV86xVICv8rBHA2C8znEUj6UehOboJwzNKlwhYXPcuxoGGctXTd7ohIMTj4p0Naf5JOHs93jTkcYVQB0rRAsyRLCxHJfySQRgqBMbd1WXmB@zcnnfiE4klWTP81x2fBEytC6IPH0xlcASIjpQUpRWg8TfncQ9tB9fTFVKab7wWZyXTkLrEmxLooPkd8DxNpuitnfH4tp3B4JmbyWiw3rA2Ry4x23tif5mc1cPr@VId3Ct45eGfgnZnVoLm9rtdx82iOJegOQvBu1xZ3@XxUhQDtroPZkfRHSLViLm0YWgQwwBxgQ8PApomS54wzluXCuIVvAoOXuIH@qPLAvoZM6FvjcNgBuxtZqJyGCEWS0ACKKgRs8LnaMRG4VMseLrHLYcvur@YB1ZU1zGFW4tpiEX33gPTYCidjFztPxCWPBMxeL@Gq43dwEybfKfyGsSb5bqcR0LMfEkBGIXgJgcAo5ow/Lt8zmoUKCOZ4IdmqHUdl@aJ1LyF5IMGTPjiI@qAGU0KYVB4NDb1YHV21DIsd8vk9ZB2Q6Uh4YD9Afx0CxcNdhIpDcBksCocxAixeEEfRgQFXfb5HoMhxAakddMe2H8pYUOx@ltX7SovQwMYwjqrP9SZ3xo446lP4lfGOPFIygWibDS4yf@rXjfb4y2qDwMZeeW3r1@ctpc3zzuXGDjJF5Z/3P7NzPj@XgKYk0fXY9eR8DWnC6nFPYHp5FwaI@m5l@w3fr9ewn67QPiAtsMDE/WoUDSQ7ccXExeHjmWi8WrXY/XSppq/r8jsyg1P1NdgBO02a0sENTOk1SNnT1/rR6oTPkhEmBQblE/YZnmv7XjRGvL7pskZhVDgqOM8485EEJJi7HMu9DQdsxFUENaDhNHalIxoQPxPGjmRct0eFRqHM@VfaKunvOnT/KF/dqVW3cehZsbFBhjP2YZP3NTst1AtXhS98fipp8bpGml6I9cm6tcZU1CXgiytgq2aeaNirvo2csr3Db8aWeY8Vrw61ttra2u5g7byS1apejw9HKNjp2U50rlyF7laXcgs7aoQE96fQdieWWKLtI@z6bnUHEfe233KuwEqGZ@4RA/5FfiGsrgOyQGeKM3aV@7KuY3fN@GfsctMAwdrm540EeAC33BU@cVVrwfQlyPY7qUIanHAHtviEyVtodIR64eiIi7vo@07XO/LTugPGa6xwMYZbnOc6s2wWZMLZ6oDR4rhGYElRDUwAldQ8hxGz4czH50QDclCGACMFJNbkn7LfCqOII@Qyj7HL4jcVWlGAxcDfdkdrB2f/4eDe@sGnlVAsOprIFYu/QgzXLDHAKrlp@WG0fY@D/QBchijr@z30zDpK3CURT9xDUdnwmCpRDay7eahFDFMH5LqLXlE95DxynFRI6NFnZqoNIa9fVPiApPkX@YuNqbFCgRwD1oCiI9puaV9v1BobvlONa4Ni7gVF7GSjuB78EkcLU4aHMdFRbxnHS7pGrqyxl1pFzGjP2R8ZTs0xRpyvc4Vu@C9pZl6lmQGaGUUTW/u3982D02NZtH6of2xeHjcvpXaB1x9yPO0OTPfWIvWBWfSLXfh7ColOLgcWaUINDi3LDQfkcBZasN0rmsWHYhDCw9e@JXeptCJOyYLEd3TSh4drDi2Szf7wPdZjl@hdqMwbu7Fc61SwzAD3v0N7jczKfn3w2ere/nzsf17Km@dqEIQZE2Yz/CFIvydld1woJ6Pbn6qS50ibFXNtnoZBrV3G0YUvKVx@sM1LNWDpXaJ@qZpgpfCGOM0AcPwd8FnMXpXozeoGAo4xAex7xLd7BSu0h1bB7/qTwkPwJHpmaPF1Nav/rGZo2g7R3WolUQeUYMX2fKe9RGXaZUN7vo/plXL1bXVn6011B24ucEMCq6ghNxpqzei@99/tjLe8yE74onhJTAYomiCMZFvD98fzC6lpyQCI9cOGac3GwQNvULzbsjty9ZNJu53xaMGGlG2eZ7ZLUpZjWQNCV78HjOB@OCK07cLQEm93W@lSJ9INR7d4ak@QIBIGRA@@/QU)
- [Without 19th byte](https://tio.run/##nRhrV@JG9Ht/xTAFMgOEAOKuyzhaRXdLq6xVu90VqCdCkGhIAgkKAvvXt/dOEgTXnj6Ox2Ry5859v4aeGQy@/UgGYegHNcO4tcPB5KbY9YbGh5/1S9@03puPT5Zr@FNrWPS9wJ7awdC4cbwbY2jaEdwuVopD211t/xBYIdGtiZgMzeCelEqVirCmvjcOyUn9@uDkRNYFC2e@RW6tsOu5/WxWfQHXoen2@J7Rsx4Md@I4pLKXLWez8eGzg8ufJU2zGI/ofkJAbfH0HF/52jJa6EuasP292fh8fXF5JCul0lYCPPt40fh88uW6/vH8/Lh@KcuiRXSX0PT88ODi5@tPx@cXjY/NGpAhnWx2TpRWHlFaCvzIH4rl6szVa0es4cQxQ4sEAzzg@SGsHr1xL/AdOxSmY5sB0W@Jlp6X8zT9E11qUsO3Jpq/n5zUT49kTbEApZFhTwQDux8q5j2CiDHA6g48kv6RUyJJGVkzBQkGFtgw9DziOb29LHrBDkmZC@vBdAhNkb7pBBZdLF5BJ@v4SgKFM10EVo9ogTE1ZoYI4PFkaIrvE@ksFqCyogQ437EFTcACzoN8906AC33bsRhnfVkSXTOwgEOZEtslrJ/jpA/eEFZgdoUZBNbwxpmh4z3w@YFL9IdwUl6EY6LXA1IqV7aq22/e7rwjWqvt5jra4nZs@aS4MB/viXZ4/KHRnDvApCerbwRYl/lj2w37RPPPvI9u025cd@vBxcOn/nvreHz@@Mf08@zL05V5EF4OT3tHeT2VzmS0xf9gnS5JWm9Rki4R2pFtSsEkjvdojVkQicBopksL6RLnhLapoAIMqanQYJQWLgq0RrlA0fsykJSKvjdmAiLesV2L9PdKgs/tPksAwa4scYUHwAAtWc9m@1L2@PyYcaFYknor6IilBV4niKV2HwfoiWh9wvoc2YmXhKMdJKScWRLL5YrN9wwUh@jICQs4ABBj2Z@43dD2XHLCukr2bgrk5UFodu9bTj7fkd01JDiCOA6fxx6jTmwDB3R3dJ0ncPiLaejlTiwI2GG51JQn9AfiQfio4KNJSERaxzrugYJuXhqtx@nsqWPohmmgBdzdUsycFk1yWCXFCIEuaNeEiIbYpqvgVnjgaxZRMTvGPiU/gWhuHsjVQE8k6SmdjJ6RzaZcHtsygvD5RLp6WUSSuXuTdfcqH8SiREKQR8MjRfNVWV7qEglHzVgewFDuc/8DycTtEKMitnsmaLex9iUpShesRSIzE90JSQUrEVBaJF4wZQlfEKTpPsXVAABakAOT@Z7bDR7GYcfIMXO3zPNGKw@Zp0ffFQ7@saahWBq@MQcyIoACsQx2ywL@460BrAageGjkUilTLOeBTBmtvhV7Q5hoFPu6Y@QNB6g23@vAhpngexCgC4ZqeW4AAgBwgEBjaOiwXYZVIotYliFJX6i5taGmNj9r2flSR6bBr/m88CV86xVICv8rBHA2C8znEUj6UehOboJwzNKlwhYXPcuxoGGctXTd7ohIMTj4p0Naf5JOHs93jTkcYVQB0rRAsyRLCxHJfySQRgqBMbd1WXmB@zcnnfiE4klWTP81x2fBEytC6IPH0xlcASIjpQUpRWg8TfncQ9tB9fTFVKab7wWZyXTkLrEmxLooPkd8DxNpuitnfH4tp3B4JmbyWiw3rA2Ry4x23tif5mc1cPr@VId3Ct45eGfgnZnVoLm9rtdx82iOJegOQvBu1xZ3@XxUhQDtroPZkfRHSLViLm0YWgQwwBxgQ8PApomS54wzluXCuIVvAoOXuIH@qPLAvoZM6FvjcNgBuxtZqJyGCEWS0ACKKgRs8LnaMRG4VMseLrHLYcvur@YB1ZU1zGFW4tpiEX33gPTYCidjFztPxCWPBMxeL@Gq43dwEybfKfyGsSb5bqcR0LMfEkBGIXgJgcAo5ow/Lt8zmoUKCOZ4IdmqHUdl@aJ1LyF5IMGTPjiI@qAGU0KYVB4NDb1YHV21DIsd8vk9ZB2Q6Uh4YD9Afx0CxcNdhIpDcBksCocxAixeEEfRgQFXfb5HoMhxAakddMe2H8pYUOx@ltX7SovQwMYwjqrP9SZ3xo446lP4lfGOPFIygWibDS4yf@rXjfb4y2qDwMZeeW3r1@ctpc3zzuXGDjJF5Z/3P7NzPj@XgKYk0fXY9eR8DWnC6nFPYHp5FwaI@m5l@w3fr9ewn67QPiAtsMDE/WoUDSQ7ccXExeHjmWi8WrXY/XSppq/r8jsyg1P1NdgBO02a0sENTOk1SNnT1/rR6oTPkhEmBQblE/YZnmv7XjRGvL7pskZhVDgqOM8485EEJJi7HMu9DQdsxFUENaDhNHalIxoQPxPGjmRct0eFRqHM@VfaKunvOnT/KF/dqVW3cehZsbFBhjP2YZP3NTst1AtXhS98fipp8bpGml6I9cm6tcZU1CXgiytgq2aeaNirvo2csr3Db8aWeY8Vrw61ttra2u5g7byS1apejw9HKNjp2U50rlyF7laXcgs7aoQE96fQdieWWKLtI@z6bnUHEfe233KuwEqGZ@4RA/5FfiGsrgOyQGeKM3aV@7KuY3fN@GfsctMAwdrm540EeAC33BU@cVVrwfQlyPY7qUIanHAHtviEyVtodIR64eiIi7vo@07XO/LTugPGa6xwMYZbnOc6s2wWZMLZ6oDR4rhGYElRDUwAldQ8hxGz4czH50QDclCGACMFJNbkn7LfCqOII@Qyj7HL4jcVWlGAxcDfdkdrB2f/4eDe@sGnlVAsOprIFYu/QgzXLDHAKrlp@WG0fY@D/QBchijr@z30zDpK3CURT9xDUdnwmCpRDay7eahFDFMH5LqLXlE95DxynFRI6NFnZqoNIa9fVPiApPkX@YuNqbFCgRwD1oCiI9puaV9v1BobvlONa4Ni7gVF7GSjuB78EkcLU4aHMdFRbxnHS7pGrqyxl1pFzGjP2R8ZTs0xRpyvc4Vu@C9pZl6lmQGaGUUTW/u3982D02NZtH6of2xeHjcvpXaB1x9yPO0OTPfWIvWB6Re78PcUEp1cDizShBIcWpYbDsjhLLSKfrFXNIsPxSCEh699S65SaUWbkgWJr@ikDw/XHFokm/3he6zHLtG7UJg3dmOx1qlglQHuf4f2GpmV@frgstW1/fnY/7yTN8/VHAgjJoxm@DuQfk/K7rhQTia3P1Uhz5E2K@baPA1zWruMkwtfUrj7YJeXar7Su0T9UDXBQuENcZgB4Pg74LOYvSrRm9UNBJxiAtj3iG/3ClZoD62C3/UnhYfgSfTM0OLralb/Wc3QtB2iu9VKog4owYrt@U57icq0y4b2fB3TK@Xq2@rO1pvqDlxc4IIEVlEzbjTTmtF177/bGS95kZ3wRfGOmMxPNEEYybaG74/nF1LTkvkPy4cNw5qNcwdeoHi3ZXfk6heTdjvj0YINGds8z2yXpCzHsgaErn4OGMH1cERo24WZJd7uttKlTqQbTm7x0J4gQSQMiB58@ws)

Comment: Sorry, but this is invalid as the code does not contain anything. The rules specifically state "the nineteenth byte of your source code," not "the nineteenth byte of your filename."

Comment: So, isn't filename a source code, although filename is main routine for Pxem?

Comment: Even though programs are stored in the filename, that doesn't make the filename the source code. Also, please delete your answer instead of marking it as disqualified.

Comment: [How about this?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/221221/revisions)

Comment: Yep, that works!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 65 bytes

```
a="Exchange Chat"
"#";a+=" - The Nineteenth Byte"
print"Stack",a
```

The nineteenth byte is the quotation mark before the hashtag. Removing it turns line 2 into a comment.

Works in Python 3 for 67 bytes, by adding brackets for the `print()` function.

Comment: Welcome to code golf! Nice idea and competitive as well!

Comment: Good first answer indeed! You can save a byte by removing the space between `print` and `"Stack"`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9FWybUiOSMxLz1VwTkjsUSJS0lZyTpR21ZJQVchJCNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEPBqbIkVYmroCgzr0QpuCQxOVtJJ/H/fwA)

Comment: @Makonede Thanks for your help. I have updated the answer.

Comment: "Hashtag" .....

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 63 bytes

```rust
||print!("Stac{:.105}","k Exchange Chat - The Nineteenth Byte")
```

The nineteenth byte is the `0` in the formatting parameter.

Removing it changes the format string in the closure to print 15 characters from the argument instead of up to 105.

With the 19th byte: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6GpUK2g8b@mpqAoM69EUUMpuCQxudpKz9DAtFZJRylbwbUiOSMxLz1VwTkjsURBVyEkI1XBLzMvtSQ1Na8kQ8GpsiRVSfO/poamNVftfwA)
Without the 19th byte: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxDkAwFAXQ3VdcndoEicHCRqwWfqCRRxvxIjwJwbfXOft5SJgYq/WsDR7o8L7b7llirXqx41NmefGpRC1or9FZngmNs4IUgyN0nkmIWBzqW0iZYLSpoi/8)

*Thanks to @ErikF for his inspiring [C solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221206/101806)*

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer!

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 101 bytes

```
console.log([[,].splice().length?"":" - The Nineteenth Byte","Stack Exchange Chat"].reverse().join``)
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBCoMwEAXQqwyzUtAcoJuCpdtu2p0IhvhJYsNEkkHa06f0HeDt9rTVlXjoKHlDay5LzQkmZd/N87CYeqTo0PUmQbyGK/OFaaRXAD2iQAHRQNNXwQM/1bo33T8uWPGgW7DKiyk4Uer/2HOUde1b@wE), [without the 19th byte](https://tio.run/##FcxBCoMwEAXQqwyzUtAcwI3Q0m037U4EQ/pJYsOkJIO0p0/xHeDt9rDVlfjRUfILrbksNSeYlH23LMNqaooOXW8SxGuYmSemkZ4BdI8CBUQDXX4KHvih1r3p9nXBigddg1VeTcGBUs9jz1G2rW/tDw)

It's not the best answer in JavaScript, but I think it's interesting because the 19th byte is `p` of `splice`, making `slice`:

```
[,].splice.length == 0 //Falsey
[,].slice.length == 2 //Truthy
```

It might be golfed more, but idk.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the x in `Exchange`.

Comment: @GingerIndustries oof let me fix that real quick

Answer (score 3):

## [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost) `-A`, 113 bytes

```
>%?"Stack Exch2/"+\"nge Chat"@
^/+"/% - tahC egn"<
?>"he Nineteenth Byt6/"+@v
^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
^<<"
```

The 19th byte is the `\` on the first line.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/307VXim4JDE5W8G1IjnDSF9JO0YpLz1VwTkjsUTJgStOX1tJX1VBV6EkMcNZITU9T8mGy95OKSNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEPBqbLEDKjRoYwrzgYfAEkr/f//X9cRAA) or [verify that it's deterministic](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/307VXim4JDE5W8G1IjnDSF9JO0YpLz1VwTkjsUTJgStOX1tJX1VBV6EkMcNZITU9T8mGy95OKSNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEPBqbLEDKjRoYwrzgYfAEkr/f//X9fxv24YAA).
[Try it online without 19th byte](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/307VXim4JDE5W8G1IjnDSF9JWykvPVXBOSOxRMmBK05fW0lfVUFXoSQxw1khNT1PyYbL3k4pI1XBLzMvtSQ1Na8kQ8GpssQMqM@hjCvOBh8ASSv9//9f1xEA) or [verify that that is deterministic](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/307VXim4JDE5W8G1IjnDSF9JWykvPVXBOSOxRMmBK05fW0lfVUFXoSQxw1khNT1PyYbL3k4pI1XBLzMvtSQ1Na8kQ8GpssQMqM@hjCvOBh8ASSv9//9f1/G/bhgA).

#### Explanation:

**Explanation of the language in general:**

Lost is a 2D path-walking language. Most 2D path-walking languages start at the top-left position and travel towards the right by default. Lost is unique however, in that ***both the start position AND starting direction it travels in is completely random***. So making the program deterministic, meaning it will have the same output regardless of where it starts or travels, can be quite tricky.

A Lost program of 2 rows and 5 characters per row can have 40 possible program flows. It can start on any one of the 10 characters in the program, and it can start traveling up/north, down/south, left/west, or right/east.

In Lost you therefore want to lead everything to a starting position, so it'll follow the designed path you want it to. In addition, you'll usually have to clean the stack when it starts somewhere in the middle.

**Explanation of the program:**

All arrows, including the reflects `/` in the strings, will lead the path towards the leading `>` on the first line. From there the program flow is as follows:

- `>`: Travel towards the right
- `%`: Put the safety 'off'. In a Lost program, an `@` will terminate the program, but only when the safety is 'off'. When the program starts, the safety is always 'on' by default, otherwise a program flow starting at the exit character `@` would immediately terminate without doing anything. The `%` will turn this safety 'off', so when we now encounter an `@` the program will terminate (if the safety is still 'on', the `@` will be a no-op instead).
- `?`: Clean the top value on the stack. In some program flows it's highly likely we have a partial string on the stack, so we use this to wipe the stack clean of that potential string. (Minor note: if the stack was not empty when `?` is encountered, the next operation will be skipped.)
- `"`: Start a string, which means it will push the integer code-points of the characters used.
- `Stack Exch2/`: Push the code-points for these characters, being `83 116 97 99 107 32 69 120 99 104 50 47` respectively
- `"`: We're done pushing code-points of this string
- `+`: Add the top two values together: (50+47=) `97`
- With 19th byte:

  - `\`: Reflect the direction downwards
  - `<`: Change the direction towards the left
  - `"` : Start a string again
  - `nge Chat - %/`: Push the code-points `110 103 101 32 67 104 97 116 32 45 32 37 47`
  - `"`: We're done pushing code-points again
  - `+`: Add the top two values together: (37+47=) `84`
  - `/`: Reflect the direction downwards
  - `>`: Change the direction towards the right
  - `"he Nineteenth Byt6/"+`: The same yet again
  - `@`: Terminate the program if the safety is 'off' (which it is at this point). After which all the values on the stack will be output implicitly. Using the `-A` program argument flag, these code-points will be output as characters instead.
- Without the 19th byte:

  - `"nge Chat"`: Push the code-points `110 103 101 32 67 104 97 116`
  - `@`: Similar again: terminate the program if the safety is 'off' (which it is at this point), and output the values on the stack implicitly (as characters because of the `-A` flag).

*Some things to note:*

- The leading `?` on the third line instead of a `^` is to clean a second unwanted value from the stack, which happens (among others) for the flow {first row, third character, traveling downwards}.
- The bottom row `^<<"`, and primarily the `"`, is for the flow {first row, fourth character, traveling upwards}, which would otherwise keep pushing strings without changing directions.
- The trailing `v` on the third line is for the flow {first row, third character, traveling right}, which skipped the `%` to put the safety off, and would end up in an infinite loop traveling left on the third line.
- The `/` in the strings are to prevent infinite loops as well. The one in `"Stack Exch2/"+` for flow {first row, second character, traveling downward}; the one in `"/% - tahC egn"` for flow {second row, fourth character, traveling left}; and the one in `"he Nineteenth Byt6/"` for flow {third row, third character, traveling left}.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 36 bytes

The nineteenth byte is the `i`, if it's removed the two strings are essentially separated by the comma operator instead. The first compressed string is manually unrolled a bit to control the position of the `i` command to be the nineteenth byte.

```
` - T” Ná2çh By’`i`Stack ExÖˆge C•t
` - T” Ná2çh By’`                   // Compressed string " - The Nineteenth Byte", slightly manually decompressed to control the position of the next command.
                 i                  // This is the nineteenth byte, prepend to the above string, if removed, effectively becomes the comma operator instead.
                  `Stack ExÖˆge C•t // Compressed string "Stack Exchange Chat"
```

[Try it here.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YCAtIFSUIE7hATLnaCBCeZJgaWBTdGFjayBFeNaIZ2UgQ5V0&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 73 bytes

```py
x,t="hange Chat"," ";print("Stack Exc"+x,bool(t)*"- The Nineteenth Byte")
```

Sure it could be golfed a bit more... first looking for an alternative to `bool`

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 31 bytes

```
↓0000+¨ḟKȦΞ×ėCȦt¨↑30¨ -ξḞẊNτβ/y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATwAw/9odXNr///ihpMwMDAwK8Ko4bifS8imzp7Dl8SXQ8imdMKo4oaRMzDCqCAtzr7huJ7huopOz4TOsi95//8)

```
↓0000                           Drop 0 (does nothing)
     +                          Concatenate these strings:
      ¨ḟKȦΞ×ėCȦt¨               Compressed "Stack Exchange Chat"
                 ↑30            Take 30 characters from...
                    ¨ -ξḞẊNτβ/y Compressed " - The Nineteenth Byte"
```

The `3` is the 19th byte, so removing it makes `↑0¨ -ξḞẊNτβ/y` which is the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 43 bytes

```
”↶/➙→G,″ⅉ∕ι↑ι&}yσ”→¿›ⅈ¹⁹«¹”↶0δ⁶b↔Πξ[9⊕|c#ξ“
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9Rw9xHbdv0H82b@ahtkrvOo4bNj1o7H3VMPbfzUdvEczvVaivPN4PVTDq0/1HDrketHYd2PmrceWg1kAJrNTi35VHjtqRHbVPOLTi3L9ryUdfUmmTlc/seNcz5/x8A) Without the 19th byte (the `→`): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9Rw9xHbdv0H82b@ahtkrvOo4bNj1o7H3VMPbfzUdvEczvVaivPNwPVHNr/qGHXo9aOQzsfNe48tBpIgfUZnNvyqHFb0qO2KecWnNsXbfmoa2pNsvK5fY8a5vz/DwA) Explanation:

```
”↶/➙→G,″ⅉ∕ι↑ι&}yσ”
```

Print compressed(!) string "Stack Exchange Chat".

```
→
```

Move to the 20th column.

```
¿›ⅈ¹⁹«
```

If we are no longer in the 19th column, then:

```
¹
```

Print a `-`.

```
”↶0δ⁶b↔Πξ[9⊕|c#ξ“
```

Print compressed string " The Nineteenth Byte".

Comment: Both programs output `Stack Exchange Chat`.

Comment: @Makonede Whoops, I accidentally pasted in the wrong arrow. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

## [33](https://github.com/TheOnlyMrCat/33), 53 bytes

```
"Stack Exchange "1cp"Chat"p" - The Nineteenth Byte"Np
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Mzb@/18puCQxOVvBtSI5IzEvPVVByTC5QMk5I7FEqUBJQVchJCNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEPBqbIkVcmv4P9/AA) and [Try it without the `c`](https://tio.run/##Mzb@/18puCQxOVvBtSI5IzEvPVVBybBAyTkjsUSpQElBVyEkI1XBLzMvtSQ1Na8kQ8GpsiRVya/g/38A)

The nineteenth byte is the `c`, which affects the conditional `Np` at the end of the program.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 64 bytes

```php
<?="Stack Excha".(!($a="nge Chat")?:"$a - The Nineteenth Byte");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WKbgkMTlbwbUiOSNRSU9DUUMl0VYpLz1VwTkjsURJ095KSSVRQVchJCNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEPBqbIkVUnT@v9/AA)

A kinda trivial answer: the 19th byte is the `!`. Note that in PHP's ternary conditions `a?b:c`, if `b` is missing, `a`'s value is used instead.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 78 bytes

```
exit(('%s %s %s '+10//10*'- The Nineteenth Byte')%('Stack','Exchange','Chat'))
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7Uis0RDQ121WAGC1LUNDfT1DQ201HUVQjJSFfwy81JLUlPzSjIUnCpLUtU1VTXUg0sSk7PVddRdK5IzEvPSU4FM54zEEnVNzf//AQ)

Poor attempt but different. removing the 19th character will make it `0//10` and therefore the second string won't be printed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 101 bytes

```python
def f(gh):
	gh()
	"#";print(" - The Nineteenth Byte")
f(lambda:print(end="Stack Exchange Chat"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcqxDoJADADQmfuKpizXgckNwqJxdcEfKFzvStRKTAf4@nPgzW87XL92qTVJhhyLUh@aopFCgy0O2281jwgdPFXgsZq4iLnC9XBBCjm@@TMn7s8olkacnJcX3PdF2YrATdmRqNY/) Minus the 19th byte:

```python
def f(gh):
	gh()
	#";print(" - The Nineteenth Byte")
f(lambda:print(end="Stack Exchange Chat"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcqxDoJADADQmfuKpi7XwckN4wJhZdEfqFzvSoBCTAf5@nPwze84XXe71ZokQ45FqQ1N0UihueD9@MzmEeEKLxUYZxMXMVfoThekkOPK2ztx@49i6YFP52mB4TspWxHolR2Jav0B)
Explanation: Removing a " allows the # symbol to be used as a comment. Yes, I know this isn't very golfed.

*-3 and fixed thanks to [Makonede](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/94066/makonede).*

Comment: -3 bytes: `print(end="Stack Exchange Chat")`

Comment: @Makonede Ooh, nice catch! I'll add that.

Answer (score 2):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (c/golf), 50 bytes

```php
O+"Stack Exchange"+" Chat"" - The Nineteenth Byte"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4pBKWzJlhNZcFVbNjIFWUhRRyALye0H8CVCHmPVyrJPkiEc4f56rrvnRSNbzl3ulg@WNdPd8/QzPd09JurdR9H3V3EaJasJP8iLSbx4PRs1zZEkvqsMRcXTkq8JZXF6Xxkq4rmQmfBpnHKWJCxZpPf00dSjHy8@vWf98vX64xXzy9e/HV2x/fL19OIt@6V8vfrE@qXw6fm1IXvx6dwQ/XTx/uj6r3buMBs/Wuxf/b84evboGpYVk9EszFjHKRVMKcCqTYxGbL@cuzj5HSdTmCSPvjH8fnCwJoPLkAy6CTJJ4qBgReb48vKchPDjkJwcoG8GkKt3QgD0DawPYbLijnOTjp1mk/yAXbkZB1fWyeWp/f2ya10XYfQHO/kKk@k9t7oWezsLC8tiPfZxBouD8YLztJix46eCW98dULSGwlYHjPFwzgK0Omw2YellmOXcdthzsxGnBYuHzQaMEgyXdaarNIIRUo7gvZgv3XyZ3vjj4NlzvRew0YjBHMnD08OBN2/QfLxkj7O44PkyjHizAd8TbsM4qNsChsus2@I2vZ3eZuz55WZsO4NXlkNQGvGU2RptwNqv2g4TJtToDozepjDc7YoRwNngSc7NgRcBJ5px4Gy6yFi6mt/xLJd4mB3nk/g@LpRVWB3d6bvaI/HssL7HuqwjkXe7DtDd9tqwBCKNHZbxYpWlTAWOUKPYGa5jeAizOLxLuEIBIJLFI8/sCNZTQNi3b0yBi@gtIiI@tx1JT1zjehz0XdijQA@vocOjKEMWRNLJamnjljLJaY/B2yZgkRhyYU3AuG23S0xWW2waKIMHGhQDI5BI4DsgW4Z5wQoI0LwIswKE5QZ0FKO4oZGDniiwxvnaChY@@w5tdKMkg@Bj6BbxIgXYGLHeGKBFipF8tVwi4Y6KKjVi0m/GH9BukI02VCgvU4hjSGoYuRK5YOVjW598MXCKA5jgBpjYEKYKMsqJwlUbcSPUMEkWkb3vuX0HHcRh7QQ5mK6SJMyeTEfL/bkytudDWyOjBaX@Kl3TpiX6uIRMCnWeHp0cv/3y2875r5eGw6bZu7jWrr9pd6di@N3Z9RaLBc/IZJhO2D9WoXpFsw/mEnubSwgC3rU1F2c1XJDyflW5KvNCqTJbpbhDQ5mYO8Uit1WupAMAoV3EEaPZu9X0xt8fSxxio1uUHjSAfAnHqpjaIAr@7ybJxFJ5hwqTi0bWDcCh0AZEyRPrV@QOWH@v6ic6j7F4yKwiW3ELYlCPY0jC@DSEDIITFkaWVZKAfqLvsjYRHZ@PF4sEZu6qDGz1tXTrRw51ft4jE@bdBswEMaZ/KkYI2mKRJLYJ1WWeCxXif4CcbkDGKvz@6MOFi7VYBBq8nt30Pc@DcAJX4FW95fE/@eeC4WNoxKjhLTIAby5@@PS5F/RVSccMh1UdH/Tpi8ceCJyenZ902BSS47ChQ1uuh2k4CpduwlPqAAyuVOskOINzt42MdUWsTVjasODYMfUSUIsPiIshFJUYJ3XeiObLtR0gkuJxmUKQpniMy@SPcRHN7A4ws9FpAUdM/kVYp9pH7QHTQ4zhgkI2QG6xbYOE7LTIP0OOqWVlF2mCg7wNe1tKYqneoko9bJFhraM29mbsPJOR0Wgf@i0qBQLnFeCsLplBgrSdlvd1in@l5AeQBJuC0nteJNAi2i3a@hZuKFbUSZxKiPHUtikGsImIZhnCcSG2HUeERuANa@HCw6HWQSx6IhYV3SZmEMncUIFGNmW@LaEel04JeT3ztpxBTXMvtMwX3DqIIIjZYLlY8tQ2FnatzKL2AlAFc1FdIYYD39v/hcZlQ2KLLmYK0CfoFLR9EOYu9oQgDv0GveEasLQKSRsGWTeg9glPOUg6knOwQ2sR32ihEzDf7HNKGktPfgNP@Fdo/TBDbPi5U9l6umvsYPbbEDzfiBFYJanyYoj/2h7I3rIm4nW2lFXLuqBW2sa65ajCBVHqlM3oRgpVqtfUUNq7OSqaJ6VOGeiEdslcF7KvY5WiagJLEg9TaXZb2ZN1ztwBmY8kC5clC3g6xGUJSRP7WaGOtVp0Qev1UHQsWuNbatEbCtbu604OeGx4c5g6b5kBf1Xkavd1TIj@UADqakCUWyHHYhrH0DK2R3TgjfUkhJ8oDXcFpmLJF3uOPTMdBrEBJIXDeMoD5aXv1IdqFBbqITvVfrekyVHf0ZYDHaxLz0LmCOlXbyM6jWjH9r6KVyh1yt2pYWG9pNfw0NngQexrHQvzGtc6JBOYRkgB6pZNGTJo38LFEIWGvR7Zk0RRmV3faMFoUTn9b35IzJt6YnZ/qLRbr/R3YrPikLhu0JhvejmUtAvWA9bra5ZJFqjvwznr9eGM9U1h/yelDyA9VmSDAEVp3YEa8RTlRLQ/8iTXvkMtTicg/pvrB4ImyRW4V1CCxRID3/GaMeMZb@csXUDfHSdFnLLH8Al4Y5MF3GMLfs8z0FkuUp4WcYg3DzjJC/bI2Sx84CAoDaF4weZhuoLweXqNo@jdHTIOVBAT@Sop8IcGWlwnPCXSM2XUkmuUmXpaZM082tsu6W0HosUOKlIe3enDBGvjE3idThI@YV9K2F@0lWf8Jpo5Y5HSmREa6/XUu0PiDSnaMaC/6Dx4QMG6Vvgw6VXyYlDNiofMPPwH5jFA1YH8Ha/FhMAhqzSXNOgyIxuiDU9oqpLrizqAsjsBVBujCxrBocTQWkwWAzbn82iJYZay0ZfD/9eV0Z/gyki5slPjSyB9ka4cbmdfrFoDGacPWUXA1xK@KqA7dTjLF@2eyjymAQ2vVaY/9KWuNhyamjKVaP1v/42@zEGGGa0/bA9M6Uqbuy4blFm3Ov3Tlx/V25a3H5RrVG5AOhWSDFocBxVtI02iBkp0u1pNQP4d3BO/lJmNZsU7ZvYuUu2s2rWjqKF/6A/2DFreiStDYHRYXbMAbV6TUnnxcPVZ2Ks0tNeC6DWjw/WS59eVvD1H9wG@1t6nwf/QECEwfOJWRLr51@2Q2Rv54CGu2u1jk0QNgoh/MUkPkujKkwCrT/g0hCQJnqkOM05hMp7QD09hVECZau9Gbew5ccRhW26@aEzXQOgG5Y8P8zBOsVllYXYfuWS004HvDw7@xEWXTPy3kO0Rmuo17uX7vwE)

Every Knight program is actually one expression. It has to manually chain each statement, typically using `;`.

So for example:

```php
OUTPUT "Hello"
OUTPUT "World!"
```

will only output `Hello` because output only has one argument. Everything else is undefined behavior, but almost all interpreters ignore it.

So therefore, we can easily truncate a program by breaking the "link".

So in my program, the nineteenth byte is this `+`.

```php
O+"Stack Exchange"+" Chat"" - The Nineteenth Byte"
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

When the `+` is there, it is parsed as this:

```php
# Concatenate " Chat" and " - The...", append to "Stack Exchange" and output
OUTPUT +("Stack Exchange" +(" Chat" " - The Nineteenth Byte"))
```

When we remove it, it is parsed as so:

```php
# Concatenate "Stack Exchange" and " Chat", then output
OUTPUT +("Stack Exchange" " Chat")
# ignored because we no longer are concatenating
# " - The Nineteenth Byte"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [AsciiDots](https://github.com/aaronduino/asciidots), 63 bytes

```
/' kcatS'_$-..----\
\$_'Exchange Chat'~$' - The Nineteenth Byte
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxOzsxMyS8p/v9fX10hOzmxJFg9XkVXT08XCGK4YlTi1V0rkjMS89JTFZwzEkvU61TUFXQVQjJSFfwy81JLUlPzSjIUnCpLUv//BwA)

I feel like I can still save a byte or two but I am unsure.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 51 bytes

```lisp
O"Stack Exchange "Y" - The Nineteenth Byte""Chat".y
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhY3jf2VgksSk7MVXCuSMxLz0lMVlCKVFHQVQjJSFfwy81JLUlPzSjIUnCpLUpWUnDMSS5T0KiFaoSbATAIA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
; Output "Stack Exchange " without a trailing newline
O"Stack Exchange "
; 19th character is Y; with it, yank " - The Nineteenth Byte" into the y variable
; Without Y, the string by itself is a no-op and y keeps its initial value of ""
Y" - The Nineteenth Byte"
; Concatenate "Chat" with y and autoprint the result
"Chat".y
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html), <s>428</s> 447 bytes

```
0 _ _ * 3
1 _ _ * 32
2 _ _ l halt
3 _ S r 4
4 _ t r 5
5 _ a r 6
6 _ c r 7
7 _ k r 8
8 _ _ r 9
9 _ E r a
a _ x r b
b _ c r c
c _ h r d
d _ a r e
e _ n r f
f _ g r g
g _ e r h
h _ _ r i
i _ C r j
j _ h r k
k _ a r l
l _ t r 1
32 _ _ r H
H _ - r I
I _ _ r m
m _ T r o
o _ h r p
p _ e r q
q _ _ r r
r _ N r s
s _ i r t
t _ n r u
u _ e r v
v _ t r w
w _ e r x
x _ e r y
y _ n r z
z _ t r A
A _ h r B
B _ _ r C
C _ B r D
D _ y r E
E _ t r G
G _ e * halt
```

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?d482b66461ea9ffbff019e71be6612d8)

Without 19th:

```
0 _ _ * 3
1 _ _ * 2
2 _ _ l halt
3 _ S r 4
4 _ t r 5
5 _ a r 6
6 _ c r 7
7 _ k r 8
8 _ _ r 9
9 _ E r a
a _ x r b
b _ c r c
c _ h r d
d _ a r e
e _ n r f
f _ g r g
g _ e r h
h _ _ r i
i _ C r j
j _ h r k
k _ a r l
l _ t r 1
32 _ _ r H
H _ - r I
I _ _ r m
m _ T r o
o _ h r p
p _ e r q
q _ _ r r
r _ N r s
s _ i r t
t _ n r u
u _ e r v
v _ t r w
w _ e r x
x _ e r y
y _ n r z
z _ t r A
A _ h r B
B _ _ r C
C _ B r D
D _ y r E
E _ t r G
G _ e * halt
```

Thanks to *@Makonede* for spotting the hyphen gaff.

[Try it without the 19<sup>th</sup> Byte!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?8fecf0dee5b164bb3bd7a8a294ff22fb)

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, 64 bytes

```
="Stack Excha"&if(1,"nge Chat - The Nineteenth Byte","nge Chat")
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 83 bytes

```
"nge Chat
If 01
Ans+" - The Nineteenth Byte
"Stack Excha"+Ans
```

<sup>-1 byte by replacing `i` with the imaginary number *`i`*</sup>

TI-Basic is [tokenized](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/tokens), so the nineteenth byte is `1`. Despite being 83 bytes, this is not compatible with the TI-83.

Answer (score 2):

## Batch, 70 bytes

```
set as=e Chat
set as=%as% - The Nineteenth Byte
echo Stack Exchang%as%
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 44 bytes

```
⟨`⟩τ •› °ʀ`||` - λƛ ∵∷⟑⌈th ₁ḋ`⟩:£ṅ\+c[¥h|¥ṅ]
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLin6hg4p+pz4Qg4oCi4oC6IMKwyoBgfHxgIC0gzrvGmyDiiLXiiLfin5HijIh0aCDigoHhuItg4p+pOsKj4bmFXFwrY1vCpWh8wqXhuYVdIiwiIiwiIl0=)

When removing the 19th byte it gives:

```
⟨`⟩τ •› °ʀ`||` - λ ∵∷⟑⌈th ₁ḋ`⟩:£ṅ\+c[¥h|¥ṅ]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 35 bytes

```
`/yT)6bX$`p      01D`|<<T,/-Gk5gD8/
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%60%2FyT%296bX%24%60p++++++01D%60%7C%3C%3CT,%2F-Gk5gD8%2F&i=)

[Remove the nineteenth byte(booooo)](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%60%2FyT%296bX%24%60p++++++0D%60%7C%3C%3CT,%2F-Gk5gD8%2F&i=)

The compressed literal for the whole string is > 19 bytes, so it has to be split for a working solution (unless wastl finds some insane compression exploit)

Answer (score 1):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 66 bytes

```groovy
m='change Chat'+(01?' - The Nineteenth Byte':'')
print'Stack Ex'+m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P8/11Y9OSMxLz1VwTkjsURdW8PA0F5dQVchJCNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEPBqbIkVd1KXV2Tq6AoM69EPbgkMTlbwbVCXTv3/38A)

#### Without 19th byte

```groovy
m='change Chat'+(0?' - The Nineteenth Byte':'')
print'Stack Ex'+m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P8/11Y9OSMxLz1VwTkjsURdW8PAXl1BVyEkI1XBLzMvtSQ1Na8kQ8GpsiRV3UpdXZOroCgzr0Q9uCQxOVvBtUJdO/f/fwA)

Comment: Exploring some other answers, I can go down to 65 bytes if I instead multiply like https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221146/58776: `m='hange Chat';z=01;print'Stack Exc'+m+' - The Nineteenth Byte'*z`

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 78 bytes

```
v>"xe kcatS" >:#,_#@"etyB htnee"v
v^"chang"<>:#,_@#"  - The Ninet"<
>"tahC e"^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HckxCoAwEATA3lccm1Y/IBKC9jZaKzGsRoRUZ9DXR3Da2bjf6WAp2eKhXMHrBLGtqVfjQH17iZpI5CovCNGnA93fzkCkkTlSxjNR0VUW6uMgxFLKBw)

The 19th byte is the '#' right before '@' on the first line. If it is removed, execution will stop at '@'.

#### Explanation

```
v>"xe kcatS"          Pushes the first section of the string
v^"chang"<
>"tahC e"^

>:#,_                 Prints it

#@                    '#' is the 19th byte, it will skip the '@'. If it's removed
                      the execution will stop at '@'

   "etyB htnee"v      Push the second section of the string (there is an extra space
"  - The Ninet"<      because one char is lost when printing)

>:#,_@#               Prints it
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 60 bytes

```javascript
e="Exchange Chat "+
"- The Nineteenth Byte"
print("Stack",e)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P9VWybUiOSMxLz1VwTkjsURBSZtLSVchJCNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEPBqbIkVYmroCgzr0RDKbgkMTlbSSdV8/9/AA)

[Similar to](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221334/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 61 bytes

```julia
s=" Exchange Chat"*
" - The Nineteenth Byte";print("Stack"*s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v9hWScG1IjkjMS89VcE5I7FESYtLSUFXISQjVcEvMy@1JDU1ryRDwamyJFXJuqAoM69EQym4JDE5W0mrWPP/fwA)

port of [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221334/98541)

`*` is the 19th byte.

with the `*`, the expression is incomplete so it continues an the next line. Without it, the expression ends and the next string is useless

[Try it without the 19th character!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v9hWScG1IjkjMS89VcE5I7FEiUtJQVchJCNVwS8zL7UkNTWvJEPBqbIkVcm6oCgzr0RDKbgkMTlbSatY8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 68 bytes

```
BEGIN{a="Stack ";b=" - The Nineteenth Byte";print a"Exchange Chat"b}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd06860VYpuCQxOVtByTrJVklBVyEkI1XBLzMvtSQ1Na8kQ8GpsiRVybqgKDOvRCFRybUiOSMxLz1VwTkjsUQpqfb/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 125 bytes

```
S;t;a;\;c;h;a\ch;a$].\\;aC;$@h;\;n;"T;h;e\a;tt;e;e;n\;{;";.t;e;@\t;h;..;k;{32;"E;x.n;g;e;{;C;.;g;e;{;"C;{;'45;}.N;i;n;e;{;B;y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY2xCsMwDAX/xQS6aWib6ZZQ07VLO6qDCCYOAXfxkGL67akC4cEh6UAvp9WmT/lu25OKoYxkTEdH9xZVLNIN2UUhvNwlNWoleYrSCMi@DVpdirDQLmfCnVUKk5tGRI4pRMfp2vOTB7O/3I83vP4P)
[Try it without 19<sup>th</sup> Byte!](https://tio.run/##LY2xCsJAEET/5RDstlBTvSZ42NqYci2WcORC4GyuiBx@e7IBGRhm58FOTqtNn/LdthcVQxnJmI5ub1HFIqc@e18Ig6OkRq0kV1EaATmuXqtDERba9UJ4sEphctKIyD@F6Ha@dfzkyewvj/KOr@8)

### Expanded versions:

Original:

```
       S ; t ; a ; \
      ; c ; h ; a \ c
     h ; a $ ] . \ \ ;
    a C ; $ @ h ; \ ; n
   ; " T ; h ; e \ a ; t
  t ; e ; e ; n \ ; { ; "
 ; . t ; e ; @ \ t ; h ; .
  . ; k ; { 3 2 ; " E ; x
   . n ; g ; e ; { ; C ;
    . ; g ; e ; { ; " C
     ; { ; ' 4 5 ; } .
      N ; i ; n ; e ;
       { ; B ; y . .
```

Without 19th:

```
       S ; t ; a ; \
      ; c ; h ; a \ c
     h ; a ] . \ \ ; a
    C ; $ @ h ; \ ; n ;
   " T ; h ; e \ a ; t t
  ; e ; e ; n \ ; { ; " ;
 . t ; e ; @ \ t ; h ; . .
  ; k ; { 3 2 ; " E ; x .
   n ; g ; e ; { ; C ; .
    ; g ; e ; { ; " C ;
     { ; ' 4 5 ; } . N
      ; i ; n ; e ; {
       ; B ; y . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 59 bytes

```
"Stack Exchange "0`sp"Chat"&o"etyB htneeteniN ehT - "l*[o];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/18puCQxOVvBtSI5IzEvPVVBySChuEDJOSOxREktXym1pNJJIaMkLzW1JDUv008hNSNEQVdBKUcrOj/W@v9/AA)

This code stashes a `0` or `1` depending on whether or not the 19th character is deleted.  Then that value is pull back to conditionally print the extra characters after the string both outputs have in common is printed.

```
1. Handles the string both outputs have in common

"Stack Exchange "              - push the start of the common string
                 0`sp          - full code, push 0, increment, save "1"
               -- or --
                 0sp           - w/ 19th char dropped, saves "0"
                     "Chat"    - push the rest of the common string
                           &o  - print stack as string, reverse order 

2. Deal with the optional string

"etyB htneeteniN ehT - "        - push remaining string, in reverse
                        l*      - load saved value multiply top of stack
                          [o]   - while top of stack!=0, print as char
                             ;  - exit to avoid printing the stack
```